# How to read a zip file from remote URL using spring resource?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to use a zip file from remote URL inmemory only, using spring `Resource` class:

```
UrlResource url = new UrlResource("https://path.to.TheFile.zip");
System.out.println(url.getFile().lastModified()); //=0, so probably it did not work
```

Result:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://path.to.TheFile.zip (The syntax for the filename, directory or media is invalid)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
```

What might be wrong here?

I cannot use `url.getInputStream()` as I cannot pass the IS into a ZipFile:
`ZipFile(url.getInputStream()) //error`

Comment: Could the 'https' (secure) be the reason?

Comment: I also tried simple `http` with same error.

Comment: Wiat... Why do you have both the "file:" pseudo-protocol and https protocol? Which is it? File is for file system paths, http(s) for http paths. They're not both applicable at the same time.

Comment: You're right, that was a type. I removed it.

Answer (score -1):

According to `getFile()`'s [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html#getFile--): (emphasis mine)

> This implementation returns a File reference for the underlying URL/URI, *provided that it refers to a file in the file system*.

You should use `getInputStream()` instead. You could then just store the byte array into a local in-memory data structure (for instance, using [`StreamUtils.copyToByteArray`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html#copyToByteArray-java.io.InputStream-)) and process it (take a look at [How can I convert byte array to ZIP file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8367155/851811)).

In order to use `ZipFile` as suggested in the edited question, you'd need to write the byte array to a temporary local File (hint: [File.createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`FileCopyUtils.copy()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html#copy-byte:A-java.io.File-)), and then instantiate ZipFile straight away from it.

Remember closing the Stream if necessary and deleting the temporary File when you're done with it.

Comment: But `new ZipFile(File file)`  can only take a `File` as argument, no item or byte streams...

Comment: Read the stream into a byte array, save it to a temporary local `File` (hint: [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) and instantiate `ZipFile` straight away from it. Remember closing the `Stream` if necessary and deleting the temporary `File` when you're done with it.

Comment: I want/have to process the file completely inmemory, without saving the file even temporary!

Comment: Then what's limiting that requirement is the idea of using `ZipFile`. Most probably there are suitable ways to unzip an in-memory byte array. Take a look for instance at [How to decompress a gzipped data in a byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/270268/851811) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/DecompressaByteArray.htm).

Comment: Sorry, the question linked in my last comment applies to `gzip` files, not `zip`. The right question to look into would be [How can I convert byte array to ZIP file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8367155/851811).